# split array into fixed n chunks with dynamic sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I have an array say,

`var a = [1,2,3,4,5];`

which I want to split into exactly `n` number of chunks but having all the combinations in it.

Example:

when`n=3` should return

combination1: `[1],[2],[3,4,5]`

combination2: `[1,2],[3,4],[5]`

combination3: `[1,2,3],[4],[5]`

combination4: `[1,2],[3],[4,5]`

combination5: `[1],[2,3],[4,5]`

combination6: `[1],[2,3,4],[5]`

I am not able to understand where to start and stop this combination logic. Any kind of pointer or help is much appreciated.

Comment: how did you "produce" the combinations you show?

Comment: @Thomas n = number of chunks, and every chunk should have at least one element in it. So when n = 3, manually I wrote down all the combinations. Those are the combinations I want to print out via javascript.

Comment: OK, but how did you come up with the combinations you wrote down? Did you throw some dices? *Little pointer: Rearrange your combinations in this order: 1,5,6, 4,2, 3, and maybe you add 2 or 3 spaces between the groups. Do you see a pattern?* My point is, you already solved this, so you are able to understand this combination logic. Maybe you have problems putting this logic into code? Then we can work on that.

Comment: @Thomas yes, I am having problems putting logic into code. I am not able to get what conditions should I put for loop start & when to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach for getting all nested parts and iterate only the rest length of the left over array.

Basically, you need an exit condition, which is met, if the length of the wanted array is equal to the number of items. Then push the result and exit the function.

If not, then iterate over the left array and move a new part to the temporary array.

```js
function go(array, n) {
    function iter(left, right) {
        var i,
            l = left.length - n + right.length + 1;
        
        if (right.length + 1 === n) {                
            result.push(right.concat([left]));
            return;
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            iter(left.slice(i), right.concat([left.slice(0, i)]));
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(array, []);
    return result;
}


var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    n = 3,
    result = go(array, n);

result.forEach(function (a) { console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nina. This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a slightly different implementation than Nina.

```js
function combinations(n, values, log){
  if(n > values.length) 
    throw new Error(`cannot divide ${values.length} items into ${n} groups`);
  
  var results = [], 
    //you'll always have n items in your combination, by the very definition of this task
    //this array holds the state/progress during the iterations, 
    //so we don't have to concat partial results all the time
    //we'll push clones of the current state to the results.
    combination = Array(n);

  //just a utility to write a chunk to a particular index
  function updateIndex(index, left, right){
    combination[index] = values.slice(left, right);
    log && log(index, "updateIndex(" + [index, left, right] + ")", JSON.stringify(combination[index]));
  }
  
  //And by the good old Roman principle: divide et impera
  //this function always processes a subset of the array, defined by the bounds: left and right.
  //where `left <= index < right` (so it doesn't include right)
  //it is a recursive function, so it processes one chunk at a time, and calls itself to process the rest of the array
  function divide(index, chunks, left, right){
    log && log(index, "divide(" + [index, chunks, left, right] + ")", JSON.stringify(values.slice(left, right)) + " divided by " + chunks);
    if(chunks > 1){
      //I have to divide my section of the array in mutliple chunks
      //I do that by defining a pivot
      //the range where I can pivot is limited: 
      //  - I need at least 1 item to the left for the current chunk
      //  - and I need at least (chunks-1) items to the right for the remaining subdivisions
      for(var pivot = left + 1; pivot <= right - (chunks-1); ++pivot){
        //everything on the left of this pivot is the current chunk
        //write it into the combinations array at the particular index
        updateIndex(index, left, pivot);
        //everything on the right is not my buisness yet.
        //I'll call divide() again, to take care of that
        divide(index+1, chunks-1, pivot, right);
      }
    }else{
      //this is the last chunk, write this whole section to the last index
      updateIndex(index, left, right);
      //push a clone of this combination to the results
      //because further iterations in the loops, will change the values of the original
      //to produce the remaining combinations
      results.push(combination.slice());
      log && log(index, "push(" + formatCombination(combination) + ")\n");
    }
    return results
  }
  
  return divide(0, n, 0, arr.length);
}

function formatCombination(row){
  return JSON.stringify(row).replace(/\],\[/g, "],  [");
}

//an utility to log the steps in a nice fashion
function logger(indentation, fnText, memo){
  var str = "  ".repeat(indentation) + fnText;
  console.log(memo? str + " ".repeat(60-str.length) + memo: str);
}


var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var result = combinations(3, arr, logger);

console.log();
console.log( result.map(formatCombination).join("\n") )
```

Comment: nice alternative approach and all the comments are really helpful for me to understanding the code.